# Notepad++ can find but can not replace a string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a string like this:

```
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (999,'stuff',NULL,'2014-12-01 08:09:10');
```

What I want is remove some string to get the value between single quotes:

```
stuff
```

I've used 2 regex:

```
^.*\d,'
```

and

```
',NULL.*$
```

When I use count in Npp, it returns *Count: 1 match.*, but when I use replace, it returns *Replace: no occurrence was found.*

Do you have any idea?

Comment: the content between two single quotes, in my 1st string, that is `stuff`

Comment: The regex in N++ works from the cursor downwards. Just make sure your cursor is at the top of the document before doing any find/replace. Usually doing 'find' once will move the cursor so that it's just after the matched part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to combine both regexes using `|` OR operator. Finally in the replacement part, you need to give an empty string, so that it would remove all the matched characters.

```
^.*\d,'|'.*$
```

OR

```
^.*\d,'|',NULL.*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mI5dQ1/1)

**OR**

Find What: `^.*\d,'([^']*)',NULL.*$`
Replace With : `\1`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mI5dQ1/3)

Comment: Thank for your quick reply, but it still return _Replace: no occurrence was found._
I've tested on http://regexr.com/, but in Npp, it does not work.

Comment: use this `^.*\d,'([^']*)',NULL.*$` and then replace the match with `\1`. See http://regex101.com/r/mI5dQ1/2

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work, I want to remind you that I use Notepad++,

Comment: regex is correct, i think you need to enable some other options in npp.

Comment: Do you mean the _Regular expression_ option on replace dialog?

Comment: yep, i think. I didn't used npp before, but it uses a `pcre` based regex engine.

Comment: thank you @Avinash Raj, the point is as Jerry's comment, `The regex in N++ works from the cursor downwards. `, anw, thank you again!